# Craft Inequality

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

Originally the inequality looks like :

$$
\frac{1}{4}(\sqrt{\sum_{cyc}\sin(u)\sin(v)} - \sum_{cyc}\sin(u)\sin(v))
\geq\sum_{cyc}\cos(u)-(\sum_{cyc}\sin(\frac{3u}{2}))
$$
with $$u+v+w=\pi$$
after many transformations the inequality looks like :

$$
\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}2C+\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}2AB\right)}-\frac{4}{2}\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}C-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}2AB\geq\frac{4}{1}\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}\sqrt{\frac{1-C}{2}}(-2C-1)$$
with the constraint :

$$AB-\sqrt{(1-A²)}\sqrt{(1-B²)}=-C$$

and :

$$-1\le A\le B\le C\le 1$$
Furthermore we have
$$ 1\le A+B+C\le 1.5$$ 
$$ \frac{3}{4}\le A^2+B^2+C^2\le 3$$ 
$$ -1\le AB+BC+CA\le\frac{3}{4}$$
$$-3\le -\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}\sqrt{\frac{1-C}{2}}(-2C-1)\le 3$$

and $$cos(u)=A$$
 $$cos(v)=B$$
 $$cos(w)=C$$

My try :

We have :

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(A+B+C-1)\le \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}2C+\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}2AB\right)}$$

And

$$-(A^2+B^2+C^2)\le -\sum_{cyc}AB$$

We obtain :

$$
\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}2C+\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}2AB\right)}-\frac{4}{2}\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}C-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}2AB \geq    \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(A+B+C-1)-\sum_{cyc}(2C+C^2) \geq                                                        \frac{4}{1}\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}\sqrt{\frac{1-C}{2}}(-2C-1)$$

Or:

$$0\geq\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}\frac{4}{1}\sqrt{\frac{1-C}{2}}(-2C-1)+C^2+(2-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})C$$

Then I can't continue

Comment: Hello, welcome to Math.SE! We would appreciate if you could provide a few steps of your own, so that other people don't habe to start from scratch and help you quicker.

Answer (score 1):

I begin with a transformation :

$$x^2=1-C$$
$$y^2=1-B$$
$$z^2=1-A$$

We obtain :
$$ \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}2(1-x^2)+\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}2(1-x^2)(1-y^2)\right)}-\frac{4}{2}\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}((1-x^2))-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}2((1-x^2)(1-y^2))\geq-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{2}}(-2(1-x^2)-1) $$

and the constraint wich was :

$$1=A^2+B^2+C^2+2ABC$$

is:

$$1=(1-z^2)^2+(1-y^2)^2+(1-x^2)^2+2(1-z^2)(1-x^2)(1-y^2)$$

Comment: What if you tried $A=\cos(2a)$, $B=\cos(2b)$, and $C=\cos(2c)$ with $0\leq a,b,c\leq\frac{\pi}{2}$?